# How do I use part of a returned object from an API request as what the function returns?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter, node-request

I have been researching and testing how to do API calls in node js.  I'm currently trying to use part of a JSON object that gets returned from an API call in a module to return a Token.

```
var request = require("request");
var timestamp = require("unix-timestamp");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken"); 
var EventEmitter = require("events").EventEmitter;

timestamp.round = true;

//create current unix timestamp
var current = timestamp.now();

//create unix experation time
var experation = timestamp.add(current, "+5m");

//create header
var header = {"header"}

//create payload
var payload = {
   "iss": process.env.CKEY,
   "aud": "https://iformbuilder.com/exzact/api/oauth/token",
   "exp": experation,
   "iat": current
};

var signature = process.env.SKEY;

//Create assertion
var assert = jwt.sign(payload, signature);
var grant = 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer';

//set the options
var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://iformbuilder.com/exzact/api/oauth/token',
  qs: {
     grant_type: grant,
     assertion: assert 
  },
  headers: { 
     'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache' 
  }
};

var data = {};
var tkn = new EventEmitter();

module.exports = {
    token: function() {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(body);
            tkn.body = body;
            tkn.emit('update');
         });

        tkn.on('update', function(){
            data = JSON.parse(tkn.body);
            return data.access_token;
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can only use the returned item within the scope of tkn.on.  I can nesting another API call within to use the token. However, I would like to use it without having to use the same code over again. The only solution that I can get to work is writing to a file.  I'm wondering if I'm even going about this the right way. I can't seem to find any good source online to help me with this and maybe I'm asking the wrong question.

Comment: If your module uses some asynchronous method, you have to consume it asynchronously. That is, your function call has to take a parameter for a callback function, and you have to call it into your tkn.on(...) callback. Look into javacript callback pattern and, if you feel brave, Js Promises. Follow the white rabbit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a callback (or promise) to get the value. Below is an example with callbacks I'll let you research promises. I would say, understand it with callbacks first then move on to promises.

someOtherModule.js

```
var tokenGetter = require('./tokenGetter');

function doSomethingWithToken(accessToken){
    //Do what you want with the token here
}

tokenGetter.token(doSomethingWithToken);
```

tokenGetter.js

```
module.exports = {
    token: function(callback) {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(body);
            tkn.body = body;
            tkn.emit('update');
        });

        tkn.on('update', function(){
            data = JSON.parse(tkn.body);
            callback(data.access_token);
        });
    }
}
```

The reason you have to do this is because with asynchronous operations, you do not know when you will get a response. The code is no longer linear in the same way it was before.

You have to adjust your code to continue its operations WHEN you get a response instead of AFTER you do the operation.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I'm going to test this out and start looking into Callbacks and then Promises.